# IF condition need to check evrytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-events

I am using the below code to render the same as many as times,

I have two sections, one section with show-all class and another with no class.

When 'show-all' class is not available, it need to run `countIncrease` function, if class available no need to run the function,

In every time section need to check whether the class is available or not.

```
class Grid {
    init() {
        $('.grid').each(function() {
            const $this = $(this);
            // getting values & url from from html
            const dropDownUrlpath = $this.find('.grid__dropdown-select').attr('data-ajaxurl');
            const hasClass = $this.find('.grid').hasClass('grid_showall');
            // countIncrease shows the inital 6 compoents/div and rest of will be hidden
            // onclick it will display 3 components/div
            function countIncrease() {
                let limit = parseInt($this.find('.grid__component').attr('data-initcount'), 10);
                const incrementalCall = parseInt($this.find('.grid__component').attr('data-incrementalcount'), 10);
                $this.find(`.grid__content > .grid__component:gt(' ${limit - 1} ') `).hide();
                if ($this.find('.grid__content > .grid__component').length <= limit) {
                    $this.find('.grid__cta').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $this.find('.grid__cta').show();
                }
                $this.find('.grid__cta').on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    limit += incrementalCall;
                    $this.find(`.grid__content > .grid__component:lt(' ${limit} ')`).show();
                    if ($this.find('.grid__content > .grid__component').length <= limit) {
                        $this.find('.grid__cta').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
            
            if (hasClass.length === true ) {
                console.log('class exist-----'+ hasClass);
                countIncrease();
            }
            // on dropdown change taking the selected dropdown value and adding @end of the url and replacing the previous html
            $this.find('.grid__dropdown-select').on('change', function() {
                const optionValue = this.value;
                $.ajax({
                    url: dropDownUrlpath + optionValue,
                    success(result) {
                        $this.find('.grid__content').html(result);
                        countIncrease();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I written if condition, but it running once and giving false condition in both  the scenarios,

```
if (hasClass.length === true ) {
    console.log('class exist-----'+ hasClass);
    countIncrease();
}
```

How to handle it...?

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt you add a parameter to the .hasClass so it knows what to check?

```
if ( $this.hasClass ('some class') === true ) {
alert('something');
}
```

or set `if(hasClass.length > 0){}`

Answer (score 0):

keep the checking class in a variable by finding with parent div,

```
const hasClass = $this.find('.grid').hasClass('grid_showall');
```

gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set with .attr() method

```
const classInthis = hasClass.attr('class');
```

check the condition, with

```
if (classInthis !== 'grid_showall') {
    countIncrease();
}
```